# Deserializing nested XML into arrays

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I've been trying to deserialize an xml document into a class.  I've done this before, but not with this much nesting.  I'm pretty much trying to replicate a simple directory tree.  The issue I'm running into is the file aspect.  the directory section works and i can get to the files, but deserializing the file names to my class isn't quite matching up.  My XMl doc is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Directories>
<Directory Path="Path1">
<Files>
  <File Type="None">File1</File>
  <File Type="None">File2</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File3</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File4</File>
  <File Type="None">File5</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File6</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File7</File>
  <File Type="None">File8</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File9</File>
</Files>
</Directory>
<Directory Path="Path2">
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File10</File>
  <File Type="None">File11</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File12</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File13</File>
  <File Type="None">File14</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File15</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File16</File>
  <File Type="None">File17</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File18</File>
</Files>
</Directory>
<Directory Path="Path3">
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File19</File>
  <File Type="None">File20</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File21</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File22</File>
  <File Type="None">File23</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File24</File>
</Files>
<Files>
  <File Type="DLL">File25</File>
  <File Type="None">File26</File>
  <File Type="EXE">File27</File>
</Files>
</Directory>
</Directories>
```

and here is my class:

```
[XmlRoot("Directories")]
public class Directories
{
    [XmlElement("Directory")]
    public Directory[] Directory { get; set; }
}

public class Directory
{
    [XmlAttribute("Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Files")]
    [XmlArrayItem("File")]//this causes the object to structure properly, but doesn't populate the string file property in the class with or without the attribute decoration
    public XmlFileInfo[] Files { get; set; }
}

public class XmlFileInfo
{
    [XmlElement("File")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]//this works fine if this class is referenced as an array
    public /*External Enum*/ FileTypes Type { get; set; }
}
```

the above class with decorations properly populates the Type enum but with not the File string.  the following class with the decorations populates the file string with the first file in the files tree and doesn't properly populate the Type enum

```
[XmlRoot("Directories")]
public class Directories
{
    [XmlElement("Directory")]
    public Directory[] Directory { get; set; }
}

public class Directory
{
    [XmlAttribute("Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Files")]
    //[XmlArrayItem("File")]
    public XmlFileInfo[] Files { get; set; }
}

public class XmlFileInfo
{
    [XmlElement("File")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public SignatureChecker_Mtabs.Program.FileTypes Type { get; set; }
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked my class.  My issue was with the attribute for my xmlFileInfo.  I designed the class improperly and because of the time constraint am unable to correct this.  So instead I'm removing the attributes and going with this class

```
[Serializable]
//[XmlRoot("Directories")]
public class Directories
{
    //[XmlElement("Directory")]
    public List<Directory> Directory { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Directory
{
    //[XmlAttribute()]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    //[XmlArray("Files")]
    //[XmlArrayItem("File")]
    public List<XmlFileInfo> Files { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class XmlFileInfo
{
    //[XmlElement("File")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    //[XmlAttribute()]
    public MyobstruficatedEnum Type { get; set; }
}
```